# How to add a integer value that goes up each item python

Tags: python, list

i was trying to add a Interger value that goes up for the each item in the list.

i wanted something like this:

```
List = [1,1,1]
**code 
output = [2,3,4]
```

here is the code that i already tried:

```
list = [1,1,1]
nummer = []
nummer.append(list  + 1)
print(nummer)
output = [5,5,5]
```

Comment: Are you actually assigning a variable called `output` or trying to represent the output you got? It is unclear as your above code would raise a `TypeError` (because of `list + 1`). Also you might want to have a look in the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) because what you are asking requires the most basic looping

Comment: It's not at all clear what you actually want here. Do you actually need an input? If so, what happens when the input is something different, e.g. `[2,6,4]`?

Comment: well the code that i have typed is a diffrent from what i have in the question. in my main code i am converting a sentence to a list of integers. after that i am changing the numbers by adding + 1 each time  to it and converting back to a sentence. so thats why the code above may not work. and yes each time the input is diffrent.  And output is just what i am getting, its not assignd variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use a loop:

```
list = [1,1,1]

for i in range(len(list)):
    list[i] += i + 1

print(list)
```